# Updating data in a view - oracle

Tags: oracle, view, oracle12c

Hello guys I have a question on some how to update some data within a view.

I have updated the data from the table by the insert into the table command, but I was wondering if its possible to update the data using the view.

Thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Oracle, is it possible to INSERT or UPDATE a record through a view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652995/in-oracle-is-it-possible-to-insert-or-update-a-record-through-a-view)

Comment: If you updated the data in the table, the view should reflect the change immediately.  Are you sure you're looking at a view and not something else (such as a materialized view)?

Answer (score 0):

you can update data in a view, but there are very specific rules (see oracle doc)

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/view-updatability.html

as another person has commented, if you update the underlying data the view should reflect the change (assuming you have committed the change). So if this is not happening, you are more likely to be using a materialised view.