# Grant update to user Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, security, plsql

I would like to grant the right of update to a manager on a table custumer but only on the customers of which it is manager.

For example I have a table Custumer and I created a user "Jean" with the command CREATE USER, so I would like that "Jean" can modify all the customers of which it is manager.

Comment: Access is granted at the table level. You're asking for something which would grant access at the row level, which Oracle does not support. Perhaps you could use a trigger to accomplish what you're trying to do. Best of luck.

Comment: Its possible, Oracle has row level security (RLS) , [VPD](https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/virtual-private-databases#SecurityPolicies) , as well as Oracle level security ( [OLS](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TDPSG/GUID-72D524FF-5A86-495A-9D12-14CB13819D42.htm#GUID-AA80B9CE-93B0-4E39-8FEA-BEC3C4763EF5) ).  There is overlap in what to use, and typical for Oracle, its a bit complicated.

Comment: Another solution is to create a view which contains only those rows which are allowed to be updated and then grant update on that. This does require the view be updatable, which can get complicated. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1653192/3268128) for details on how that works.

Comment: Which version and **edition** of the database? The cleanest way of implementing this would be Fine-grained Access Control (i.e. DBMS_RLS policies) but that requires Enterprise license.

Comment: Is there are reason that you want to do this at the database table level?  To me this sounds like a rule that would be much easier and cleaner to enforce at an application level.

Answer (score -1):

I found this example of RLS but It's too late to edit to meet your simple USER requirements. This example caters for users with many andvarious ROLES that may be inherited from an Organizational Tree. But I hope you get the idea?

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_RLS.DROP_POLICY (object_schema    => 'CHS',
                       object_name       => 'CASE_FILE',
                       policy_name       => 'CASE_FILE_READ');

  DBMS_RLS.DROP_POLICY (object_schema    => 'CHS',
                       object_name       => 'CASE_FILE',
                       policy_name       => 'CASE_FILE_WRITE');

  DBMS_RLS.DROP_POLICY (object_schema    => 'CHS',
                       object_name       => 'CASE_FILE',
                       policy_name       => 'CASE_FILE_REGISTER');

END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE chs_security_policies AS

    ROLE_CRUM            CONSTANT VARCHAR2(5) := 'CRUM';
    ROLE_CRUO            CONSTANT VARCHAR2(5) := 'CRUO';
    ROLE_HOU             CONSTANT VARCHAR2(5) := 'HOU';
    ROLE_DCO             CONSTANT VARCHAR2(5) := 'DCO';
    ROLE_SA              CONSTANT VARCHAR2(5) := 'SA';
    ROLE_CA              CONSTANT VARCHAR2(5) := 'CA';
    CHS_ORG_TREE         CONSTANT CHAR(5)     := 'CHS01';
    READ_ACCESS          CONSTANT INTEGER     :=   63;
    WRITE_ACCESS         CONSTANT INTEGER     :=   42;
    INSERT_ACCESS        CONSTANT INTEGER     :=   64;
    ORG_CASCADE          CONSTANT INTEGER     := 2060;
    CASE_SPECIFIC        CONSTANT INTEGER     :=   48;
    QUARANTINED_ACCESS   CONSTANT INTEGER     :=  128;
    FINALISED_ACCESS     CONSTANT INTEGER     :=  256;
    READ_ONLY            CONSTANT INTEGER     :=   21;
    READ_CASE_ORG_UNITS  CONSTANT INTEGER     :=   16;
    READ_GROUP_ORG_UNITS CONSTANT INTEGER     :=    4;
    READ_WORLD_ORG_UNITS CONSTANT INTEGER     :=    1;

    FUNCTION case_file_read     (i_schema IN VARCHAR2, i_object IN VARCHAR2)
      RETURN VARCHAR2;

    FUNCTION case_file_write    (i_schema IN VARCHAR2, i_object IN VARCHAR2)
      RETURN VARCHAR2;

    FUNCTION case_file_register (i_schema IN VARCHAR2, i_object IN VARCHAR2)
      RETURN VARCHAR2;

    FUNCTION case_file_filter   (i_schema IN VARCHAR2, i_object IN VARCHAR2, i_access_requested INTEGER)
      RETURN VARCHAR2;

    FUNCTION check_case_access  (i_case_file_id IN INTEGER, i_mgr_org_unit IN INTEGER, i_dco_person_id in varchar2)
      RETURN INTEGER
      DETERMINISTIC;

    FUNCTION default_priv_mask  (i_person_id in varchar2) 
      RETURN INTEGER
      DETERMINISTIC;

    FUNCTION decode_role        (i_case_file_id IN INTEGER, i_mgr_org_unit IN INTEGER, i_dco_person_id in varchar2)
      RETURN VARCHAR2
      DETERMINISTIC;

    FUNCTION check_proxy_access (i_case_file_id         IN case_file.case_file_id%type
                               , i_dco_person_id        IN case_file.dco_person_id%type
                               , i_mgr_org_unit         IN case_file.mgr_org_unit%type
                               , i_proxy_person_id      IN case_file.dco_person_id%type)
      RETURN INTEGER
      DETERMINISTIC;

END chs_security_policies;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY chs_security_policies AS

    FUNCTION case_file_read (i_schema IN VARCHAR2, i_object IN VARCHAR2)
      RETURN VARCHAR2
    IS

    BEGIN

      RETURN case_file_filter(i_schema, i_object, READ_ACCESS);

    END case_file_read;

    FUNCTION case_file_write (i_schema IN VARCHAR2, i_object IN VARCHAR2)
      RETURN VARCHAR2
    IS

    BEGIN

      RETURN case_file_filter(i_schema, i_object, WRITE_ACCESS);

    END case_file_write;

    FUNCTION case_file_register (i_schema IN VARCHAR2, i_object IN VARCHAR2)
      RETURN VARCHAR2
    IS

    BEGIN

      RETURN case_file_filter(i_schema, i_object, INSERT_ACCESS);

    END case_file_register;

    FUNCTION case_file_filter (i_schema IN VARCHAR2, i_object IN VARCHAR2, i_access_requested INTEGER)
      RETURN VARCHAR2
    IS

      o_filter_predicate VARCHAR2(200) := '';      

    BEGIN

      CASE lower(i_object)
      WHEN 'case_file' THEN
        o_filter_predicate := 
          'BITAND(chs_security_policies.check_case_access(case_file_id, mgr_org_unit, dco_person_id), '||i_access_requested||') <> 0 ';
      WHEN 'case_file_h' THEN
        o_filter_predicate := 
          'BITAND(chs_security_policies.check_case_access(case_file_id, mgr_org_unit, dco_person_id), '||i_access_requested||') <> 0 ';
      END CASE;

      RETURN o_filter_predicate;

    END case_file_filter;

    FUNCTION check_proxy_access (i_case_file_id         IN case_file.case_file_id%type
                               , i_dco_person_id        IN case_file.dco_person_id%type
                               , i_mgr_org_unit         IN case_file.mgr_org_unit%type
                               , i_proxy_person_id      IN case_file.dco_person_id%type)
      RETURN INTEGER
      DETERMINISTIC
    IS
      o_has_access       INTEGER     := 0;
      v_prev_person      varchar2(8) := SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','CLIENT_IDENTIFIER');

    BEGIN

      dbms_session.set_identifier(i_proxy_person_id);

      IF BITAND(check_case_access(i_case_file_id, i_mgr_org_unit, i_dco_person_id), READ_ACCESS) <> 0
      THEN
        o_has_access := 1;
      END IF;

      dbms_session.set_identifier(v_prev_person);

      RETURN o_has_access;

    END check_proxy_access;

    FUNCTION check_case_access(i_case_file_id in INTEGER, i_mgr_org_unit in INTEGER, i_dco_person_id in varchar2) 
      RETURN INTEGER
      DETERMINISTIC
    IS

      o_access_granted   INTEGER     := 0;
      v_curr_person      varchar2(8) := SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','CLIENT_IDENTIFIER');
      v_single_priv      INTEGER     := 0;
      v_profile_org_unit INTEGER     := 0;
      v_quarantine_ok    varchar2(1);
      v_finalise_ok      varchar2(1);
      v_is_participant   varchar2(1);
      v_local_role       access_role.role_code%type;

      cursor user_privs is
        select 
               d.priv_id,
               b.org_unit_id,
               c.role_code
        from   
               access_user      a
              ,access_profile   b
              ,access_role      c
              ,access_role_priv d
              ,access_priv      e
        where  
               a.person_id      = v_curr_person 
          and  a.active_flag    = 'Y'
          and  b.person_id      = a.person_id
          and  c.role_code      = b.role_code
          and  d.role_code      = b.role_code
          and  e.priv_id        = d.priv_id
      ;

    BEGIN

      IF v_curr_person is null
      THEN
          RETURN 0;
      END IF;

      select 
        case
           when exists 
              (select
                      *
                 from
                      complainant a
                where
                      a.case_file_id      = i_case_file_id
                  and a.person_id         = v_curr_person
                  and a.active_flag       = 'Y'
              )
           then  'Y'
           else  'N'
        end
      into 
        v_is_participant
      from 
        dual
      ;

      IF v_is_participant = 'Y'
      THEN
          RETURN 0;
      END IF;

      select 
        case
           when exists 
              (select
                      *
                 from
                      respondent a
                where
                      a.case_file_id      = i_case_file_id
                  and a.person_id         = v_curr_person
                  and a.person_type      <> 'U'
                  and a.active_flag       = 'Y'
              )
           then  'Y'
           else  'N'
        end
      into 
        v_is_participant
      from 
        dual
      ;

      IF v_is_participant = 'Y'
      THEN
          RETURN 0;
      END IF;

      v_quarantine_ok := 'N';
      v_finalise_ok   := 'N';

      open user_privs;

      loop
          fetch user_privs into v_single_priv,
                                v_profile_org_unit,
                                v_local_role;  

          exit when user_privs%notfound;

          IF v_single_priv = QUARANTINED_ACCESS
          THEN 
               v_quarantine_ok := 'Y';
               continue;
          END IF;

          IF v_single_priv = FINALISED_ACCESS
          THEN 
               v_finalise_ok := 'Y';
               continue;
          END IF;

          IF bitand(v_single_priv, ORG_CASCADE) <> 0 
          THEN
              select 
                case
                  when i_mgr_org_unit in (
                    select 
                      a.org_unit_child
                    from
                      org_rel a
                    connect by nocycle
                      a.org_rel_type_code = CHS_ORG_TREE and 
                    prior 
                      a.org_unit_child = a.org_unit_parent
                    start with 
                      a.org_unit_child = v_profile_org_unit
                  and a.org_rel_type_code = CHS_ORG_TREE)
                  then v_single_priv
                  else 0
                end
              into 
                v_single_priv
              from 
                dual
              ;

          END IF;

          IF bitand(v_single_priv, CASE_SPECIFIC) <> 0 
          THEN
              IF v_local_role = 'CA'
              THEN
                select 
                  case
                    when exists 
                        (select
                                *
                           from
                                case_assistant a
                          where
                                a.case_file_id      = i_case_file_id
                            and a.case_assistant_id = v_curr_person
                            and sysdate between       a.access_from and a.access_to
                          )
                    then  v_single_priv
                    else  0
                    end
                into 
                  v_single_priv
                from 
                  dual
                ;
                IF v_single_priv <> 0 
                THEN
                    v_quarantine_ok := 'Y';
                END IF;
              ELSE
                  IF v_curr_person <> i_dco_person_id
                  THEN 
                      v_single_priv := 0;
                  END IF;
              END IF;
          END IF;

          o_access_granted := (o_access_granted + v_single_priv - bitand(o_access_granted, v_single_priv));

      end loop;

      close user_privs;

      IF o_access_granted = 0 THEN    
        RETURN o_access_granted;
      END IF;

      IF (v_quarantine_ok = 'N' AND (i_dco_person_id <> v_curr_person
                                 OR  BITAND(o_access_granted,CASE_SPECIFIC) = 0)) THEN
        select 
          case
            when exists 
                (select
                        *
                   from
                        quarantine a
                  where
                        a.case_file_id      = i_case_file_id
                    and a.active_flag       = 'Y'
                  )
            then  0
            else  o_access_granted
          end
        into 
          o_access_granted
        from 
          dual
        ;
      END IF;

      IF o_access_granted = 0 THEN    
        RETURN o_access_granted;
      END IF;

      IF v_finalise_ok = 'N' THEN
        select 
          case
            when exists 
                (select
                        *
                   from
                        finalise a
                  where
                        a.case_file_id      = i_case_file_id
                  )
            then  0
            else  o_access_granted
          end
        into 
          o_access_granted
        from 
          dual
        ;

      END IF;

      IF v_finalise_ok = 'Y' THEN
        select 
          case
            when exists 
                (select
                        *
                   from
                        finalise a
                  where
                        a.case_file_id      = i_case_file_id
                  )
            then  BITAND(o_access_granted, READ_ONLY)
            else  o_access_granted
          end
        into 
          o_access_granted
        from 
          dual
        ;

      END IF;

      RETURN o_access_granted;

    END check_case_access;    

    FUNCTION decode_role(i_case_file_id IN INTEGER, i_mgr_org_unit IN INTEGER, i_dco_person_id in varchar2)
      RETURN VARCHAR2
      DETERMINISTIC
    IS

      v_curr_person      varchar2(8) := SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','CLIENT_IDENTIFIER');
      v_access_granted   INTEGER     := 0;
      o_role_used        access_role.role_code%type;

    BEGIN

      v_access_granted := check_case_access(i_case_file_id, i_mgr_org_unit, i_dco_person_id);

      IF BITAND(v_access_granted, READ_CASE_ORG_UNITS ) <> 0 THEN
          IF v_curr_person = i_dco_person_id THEN
              o_role_used := ROLE_DCO;
          ELSE
              o_role_used := ROLE_CA;
          END IF;
      ELSE 
          IF BITAND(v_access_granted, READ_GROUP_ORG_UNITS) <> 0 THEN
              o_role_used := ROLE_HOU;
          ELSE
              IF BITAND(v_access_granted, READ_WORLD_ORG_UNITS) <> 0 THEN
                  select 
                    case
                    when exists 
                        (select
                                *
                           from
                                access_profile a
                          where
                                a.person_id       = v_curr_person
                            and a.role_code       = ROLE_CRUM
                          )
                    then  ROLE_CRUM
                    else  ROLE_CRUO
                  end
                into 
                  o_role_used
                from 
                  dual
                ;
              END IF;
          END IF;
      END IF;

      RETURN o_role_used;

    END decode_role;

    FUNCTION default_priv_mask(i_person_id in varchar2) 
      RETURN INTEGER
      DETERMINISTIC
    IS

      o_access_available INTEGER     := 0;
      v_single_priv      INTEGER     := 0;

      cursor user_privs is
        select 
               d.priv_id
        from   
               access_user      a
              ,access_profile   b
              ,access_role      c
              ,access_role_priv d
              ,access_priv      e
        where  
               a.person_id      = i_person_id 
          and  a.active_flag    = 'Y'
          and  b.person_id      = a.person_id
          and  c.role_code      = b.role_code
          and  d.role_code      = b.role_code
          and  e.priv_id        = d.priv_id
      ;

    BEGIN

      open user_privs;

      loop
          fetch user_privs into v_single_priv;

          exit when user_privs%notfound;

          o_access_available := (o_access_available + v_single_priv - bitand(o_access_available, v_single_priv));

      end loop;

      close user_privs;

      RETURN o_access_available;

    END default_priv_mask;    

END chs_security_policies;

/

BEGIN
  DBMS_RLS.ADD_POLICY (object_schema     => 'CHS',
                       object_name       => 'CASE_FILE',
                       policy_name       => 'CASE_FILE_READ',
                       function_schema   => 'CHS',
                       statement_types   => 'SELECT',
                       policy_function   => 'chs_security_policies.case_file_read');

  DBMS_RLS.ADD_POLICY (object_schema     => 'CHS',
                       object_name       => 'CASE_FILE',
                       policy_name       => 'CASE_FILE_WRITE',
                       function_schema   => 'CHS',
                       statement_types   => 'UPDATE,DELETE',
                       policy_function   => 'chs_security_policies.case_file_write');

  DBMS_RLS.ADD_POLICY (object_schema     => 'CHS',
                       object_name       => 'CASE_FILE',
                       policy_name       => 'CASE_FILE_REGISTER',
                       function_schema   => 'CHS',
                       statement_types   => 'INSERT',
                       policy_function   => 'chs_security_policies.case_file_register');
END;
```