# Oracle - how to perform left join on views?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, create-view

How to create a views using left join on Oracle?

I am be able to create a join table using this statement

```sql
select *
from
    concert_copy c
    left join event_copy e
        on c.concert_id=e.concert_id;
```

But when I create views using this statement gave me error

> "ORA-00957: duplicate column name"

```sql
create view concert_event as
    select *
    from
        concert_copy c
        left join event_copy e
            on c.concert_id=e.concert_id;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At least the `concert_id` column appears in both tables. `SELECT *` would result in a view having 2 columns with the same name. Resolution: specify the fields explicitly at least for one of the tables

```
create view concert_event as
    select c.*, e.eventname, ...
    from
        concert_copy c
        left join event_copy e
            on c.concert_id = e.concert_id;
```

If there are other duplicate names, use aliases. E.g. If both tables have a column `name`

```
select c.*, e.name as eventname, ...
```

Note: if you call `SELECT` directly, Oracle automatically creates generic names for duplicate columns and expressions, but in views it is required that all column names are visible from the declaration, either because they match the name of a selected column or because an alias is given.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use asterisk (i.e. SELECT *), but name ALL columns you select, giving each of them distinctive name. For example, if both CONCERT_COPY and EVENT_COPY have column named ID, you'd have to

```
select c.id concert_id, e.id event_id, ...
from concert_copy c left join event_copy e ...
```

Comment: oh I can not use asterisk? Dang, i dont know that. Thx @Littlefoot

Comment: You can, but that's USUALLY a bad idea. It is better to name all columns, especially if you write code that will be used in production. Someone, who might need to maintain your code, would know exactly what you selected. "SELECT *" is OK for *quick and dirty* selects, but - as you can see - it can cause problems.

Comment: is it possible do update on those column on view? why I can not update each column on the view?

Comment: Update? Yes, as well as insert or delete. Usual way to do that is via **instead of** trigger(s). More info here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96524/c18trigs.htm#10901

Comment: Also see the answers to [In Oracle, is it possible to INSERT or UPDATE a record through a view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652995/in-oracle-is-it-possible-to-insert-or-update-a-record-through-a-view)